# How to write fuzzy multiple substring matching when using RLIKE in Hive

Tags: regex, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, rlike

For example:

```
df.select('category').show()

+---------------------------+
|                   category|
+---------------------------+
|            money,insurance|
|            life, housework|
|           game,FPS,network|
|            game,fight,jump|
|                      hotel|
|                 trip,hotel|
|                       null|
```

I want to use `RLIKE` to write a regex expression to fuzzy match one of substrings list, `['money', 'life']`.

```
-- This is an exact match
SELECT * 
FROM tb_name
WHERE col_name RLIKE '(money|life)'

-- This is a fuzzy match
SELECT * 
FROM tb_name
WHERE col_name RLIKE '*.(money|life)'
```

BUT there is error in ast tree in the fuzzy match code snippet.

> 06-11 16:59:17-fatal  filter ast tree
>
> (TOK_QUERY (TOK_FROM (TOK_TABREF (TOK_TAB tb_name))) (TOK_INSERT (TOK_DESTINATION (TOK_DIR "hdfs://XXXX/XX")) (TOK_SELECT (TOK_SELEXPR TOK_ALLCOLREF)) (TOK_WHERE (RLIKE (TOK_TABLE_OR_COL col_name ) '*.(money|life)')) (TOK_LIMIT 2000)))
>
> 06-11 16:59:17-fatal  Filter feature: .*TOK_TAB \S* tdw_inter_db.*|.*TOK_(CUBE|ROLLUP) .*

So I can't see anything wrong with the **fuzzy match** code snippet.
So could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Comment: what fuzzy template should do? `RLIKE 'money|life'` will match strings containing any of money, life

Comment: @leftjoin I don't it is the intranet platform implementation problem here or anything else. If I try to `RLIKE 'money|life'` or `RLIKE '(money|life)', it only returns the value which is exactly equal to `money` or `life`.

Comment: Look at this: https://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=123435  `select 'life, housework' rlike ('money|life')` returns TRUE

Comment: @leftjoin Thanks sincerely. I am sure the intranet platform has some implementation problems on `RLIKE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(?i)money|life'` regexp will match strings containing any of `money`, `life`,  case insensitive - `(?i)`